# Using parallel-ssh with public key

Tags: command-line, openssh

I have configured the remote ssh server for login via public-private key pair (only).
I can login into the server and run commands using ssh:

```
ssh me@my.server.home  -i ~/.ssh/my_key echo fu
```

I'd like to send commands to the server using `parallel-ssh` from `pssh` package. 
I use `-H` option to specify list of servers (one server), `-i` to print results on screen and `-A` so that program would ask for a password to the key.
The documentation states that it is capable of passing arguments down to ssh using `-x` or `-X`. However, neither the following command work:

```
parallel-ssh -A -i -H "me@my.server.home" -X "-i ~/.ssh/my_key" 'echo fu'
```

output being:

```
Warning: do not enter your password if anyone else has superuser
privileges or access to your account.
Password:
[1] 17:03:35 [FAILURE] me@my.server.home Exited with error code 255
Stderr: Warning: Identity file ~/.ssh/my_key not accessible: No such file or directory.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

(I can see the file with `ll ~/.ssh/my_key`. )

Nor this command succeeds:

```
 parallel-ssh -A -i -H "me@my.server.home" -x '-i ~/.ssh/my_key' 'echo fu'
```

output:

```
Warning: do not enter your password if anyone else has superuser
privileges or access to your account.
Password:
[1] 17:15:06 [FAILURE] administrator@192.168.0.118 Exited with error code 255
Stderr: Enter passphrase for key '/home/local_user/.ssh/my_key':
Permission denied (publickey).
```

This second one is completely weird since `man parallel-ssh` claims that `-A` option does "Prompt for a password and pass it to ssh.  The password may be used for either to **unlock a key** or for password authentication."

So, how would one use a password-protected public key inside `parallel-ssh` command?

Comment: Maybe `parallel-ssh` passes the `~` in `-x '-i ~/.ssh/my_key'` literally instead of performing tilde expansion. Could you please try `-x "-i $HOME/.ssh/my_key"` instead?

Comment: No, that was not the problem (when `-x`, not `-X` option used). Various combinations of quotation and case were used including typing complete path. The problem is truly addressed by the links in the answer. The bug was acknowledged in that weird google forum but it seems development stalled at the point before fix.  There are now numerous github forks featuring exactly that fix as a sole change from the original.

Answer (score 4):

[This is a bug](https://code.google.com/archive/p/parallel-ssh/issues/80) in the `pssh` program which is just a collection of a python scripts. These scripts resort to parsing the `ssh` program output to interface with it.

One way to get it working is to [fix it yourself](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/128986/221781).
`dpkg -L pssh` will list all the files installed with the `pssh` package.
`askpass_client.py` is the file that needs modification.
Line 67 is

```
if not prompt.strip().lower().endswith('password:'):
```

and should be:

```
if not ( prompt.strip().lower().endswith('password:') or 'enter passphrase for key' in prompt.strip().lower()):
```

Then the command

```
parallel-ssh  -A -i -H "me@my.server.home" -x "-i ~/.ssh/my_key"  'echo fu'
```

will work.